# How do I use HAML in a dynamic link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am trying to create a link using HAML which looks like the this

```
=link_to("Last updated on<%=@last_data.date_from.month %>",'/member/abc/def?month={Time.now.month}&range=xyz&year={Time.now.year}')
```

It is not taking the Ruby code and it is displaying that as a string

> Last updated on<%=@last_data.date_from.month %>

and in the URL as well it is not taking the function `Time.now.month` or `Time.now.year` .

How do I pass Ruby code in URL and in the string ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should probably use something like this:

```
= link_to("Last updated on #{@last_data.date_from.month}", "/member/abc/def?month=#{Time.now.month}&range=xyz&year=#{Time.now.year}")
```

Note that in the second string, it's necessary to change the `'` to `"`. Also if the link text is getting long, you can use something like this:

```
= link_to("/member/abc/def?month=#{Time.now.month}&range=xyz&year=#{Time.now.year}") do
  Last updated on #{@last_data.date_from.month}
```

Comment: Hey thanks First part is working but in the URL I am still getting Time.now.year and Time.now.month

Comment: Did you change the surroundings? I mean ' -> "

Comment: Well you should :). If you have a string in ' ', it's not interpolated with any ruby expressions.

Comment: The Url should look like this is it ? ,'/member/abc/def?month=#{Time.now.month}&range=xyz&year=#{Time.now.year}'

Answer (score 7):

Everything after the `=` in HAML is a Ruby expression. Ruby doesn't interpolate strings the way HAML does, it has own way of such interpolation.

In Ruby, when you want to have string value of some variable inside another string, you could do.

```
"Some string #{Time.now}"
```

So, it should be:

```
= link_to "Last updated on #{@last_data.date_from.month}", "/member/abc/def?month=#{Time.now.month}&range=xyz&year=#{Time.now.year}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple example with easy syntax:

```
 link_to "Profile #{rubycode}", "profile_path(@profile)/#{ruby_code}", class: "active"
```